# Is it still necessary to pre-request a vegetarian meal on intercontinental flights?

Tags: air-travel, dietary-restrictions

I've been a vegetarian for over 16 years and have been requesting vegetarian meals on intercontinental flights for a while. Unfortunately for hungry me, I often end up receiving a vegan meal. I suspect this happens in order for airlines to reduce the different types of meals to prepare. But my issue with receiving a vegan meal is that they typically don't have sufficient calories/protein for me.

On a recent Air France flight I noticed once on board that they offered multiple options for the dinner and, surprise, one of them was vegetarian! But, having pre-requested a vegetarian meal, what I ended up being served was vegan and I spent the meal looking longingly at the cheese and cheesecake my fellows were eating.

Returning from Europe I flew KLM, and I noticed when I checked in that there were options to *pay more* for specific meals (but not categories of meal) but no place to specify a dietary restriction (maybe too late in the process). When I asked at the counter they told me to check in with a flight attendant upon boarding and fortunately they did have a vegetarian option on the menu.

Is this typical of the SkyTeam airlines I fly to Europe with (Delta/KLM/Air France)? In order to get an actual vegetarian meal, should I stop pre-requesting a vegetarian meal and hope that I'll be able to get a vegetarian option aboard?

Comment: What's your backup plan if, when the crew reach you, all they've got left is the chicken or the beef? (i.e. the handful of non-special veggie meals were taken by previous passengers)

Comment: You've not said - are you actually vegetarian?  This seems kinda subjective at present. I'd say no, because meat = delicious. Others would argue for vegan, and some vegetarian.  I also don't really get your question - what is 'worth it'?  I'm closing for now as subjective, but feel free to read the [help] and edit your question, then flag to reopen once it's clearer. Thanks!

Comment: (To clarify, a friend orders halal on a plane just to get his meal first, not because he wants halal, and others  who aren't vegetarian sometimes order it to avoid processed stuff with gluten in it.  So either I close as subjective or unclear at present...)

Comment: I order vegetarian because I'm vegetarian, not because I want my meal earlier. Though I once got lucky and ate two breakfasts because of the earlier meal

Comment: I think it is not just needed to ask for what you want/need, it is very important to contact the crew before serving so you do get what you need.

Comment: Are not vegan meals vegetarian meals?  It sounds like you eat a pseudo vegetarian diet, perhaps including some animal products like eggs or dairy.  For an airline to accommodate every variation on a healthy diet would be impossible.  Your best course of action would be to bring a small packet of cheese to supplement your dietary needs.

Comment: I'd say this is a bit broad now, rather than subjective. For example, from experience, BA tend to have a veggie option in long haul economy and business (but not, as I understand it in first or premium economy). But that's just one airline out of tens or hundreds.

Comment: @EdC, should I narrow it to specifically Air France/KLM/Delta since that's what I typically fly intercontinental?

Comment: @Tom how is this relevant to the question?\

Comment: The wording of your question "Should I...?" does make it sound opinion-based.  Maybe you should rephrase as a factual question: "Do airlines generally offer vegetarian meals without needing a special request?"

Comment: @raphael - my original comment regarding vegan versus vegetarian and the many variations thereof did apply to your question.  The subsequent discussion of 'vegetarianism' which was initiated by Willeke's comments strayed a bit.

Comment: @raphael - perhaps. To my mind, if it were specific to those three airlines, that would make it answerable. But I'm not a mod, nor can I cast a re-open vote, so maybe my opinion isn't so important :)

Comment: @ZachLipton fixed